# How to connect to Google Cloud run with allAuthenticatedUsers permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I set up a cloud run service and I set the access permission to  "allAuthenticatedUsers" and when I tried to access it through its URL I got the error: "Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server."
I think that to access it I only need to be connected to a Gmail account, am I correct or is there something else to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not just connected to a Google Account but you must pass a bearer token in your request. Have you checked [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) and [Authenticating for invocation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)?

Comment: Are you authenticated? How do you perform your invocation? Can you share your procedure to reproduce it?

Comment: Yes I'm authenticated with my Gmail account

Comment: How do you invoke your service?

Comment: Just accessed it from the browser as any site.